# Core Data NSFetchRequest is "logically false" and short circuits with no results

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a query for an NSFetchedResultsController that is failing in an odd manner, especially as its pretty much identical to one in another app.

Simple model, a Project entity with a to-many relation to a child Entry entity, stuff I have done lots of times:

[image: entity definition]

```
if let proj = AppDelegate.appDelegate().persistentContainer.viewContext.object(with: projId) as? Project
{
    currentProject = proj
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Entry>(entityName:"Entry")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "entryDate", ascending: true)]
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@",#keyPath(Entry.project), proj)

    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, 
            managedObjectContext: AppDelegate.appDelegate().persistentContainer.viewContext, 
            sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName:nil)
    do {
        try frc?.performFetch()
    }
    catch
    {
        print("error for entry frc perform")
    }
}
```

The performFetch fails to return any records even though they are clearly there if I print the object and I can see the associations in Base.  If I turn on SQLite debugging I get the following message"

> CoreData: annotation: logically false fetch request  (entity: Entry; predicate: (project ==  (entity: Project; id: 0x604000226b40
>    ; data: {
>       entries = "";
>       projectDescription = nil;
>       projectName = "Knickers Ice"; })); sortDescriptors: ((
>       "(entryDate, ascending, compare:)" )); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; ) short circuits. CoreData: annotation:
>   total fetch execution time: 0.0000s for 0 rows.

If I remove the predicate, records are returned so it is clearly directly due to the predicate. Have tried all the variants for creating it:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@","project", proj)
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "project = %@", proj)
```

and such.  If I have something messed up I am simply not seeing it.

Comment: Your fetch request is using relationship name("project") alone in the predicate. I highly doubt it will work. It should be something like "project.someattributename = %@". Please refer this post for using to-many relationship in predicates : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766055/core-data-filtering-a-to-many-relationship-using-predicates. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Could it be that the object with id `projId` does not exist in the persistent store anymore? What happens if you try to retrieve it with `existingObject(with: projId)` instead?

Comment: In the error message, the `entries` property of the Project is shown as “”, which suggests that your Project has no entries and therefore returning zero rows would be appropriate.  But I am amazed if CoreData is parsing the predicate and deducing this without actually executing the fetch.  Which store type are you using?

Comment: Anand - I have very similar fetch requests in other apps that work as expected.  I will review that

Comment: MartinR - All objects exist and have been saved to the store.  As mentioned, if the predicate is removed from the request, the desired "Entry" objects are returned (along with others).  I will give existingObject() a try and see if there is any difference.

Comment: pbasdf - Its an SQLite store.  And as mentioned above there are objects saved to the store and their relations are all filled in appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fetch your project at all.
You can fetch your Entries by

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "project.objectID = %@", projId)
```

**Edit:**

You are trying to filter objects by NSManagedObject. I assume it caused CoreData consufion: NSManagedObject exists only in context that are fetched, but predicates applied deeper, where that object make no sense. So you need to provide `objectID` instead (but you have it even before retrieve object by from the context).

Comment: Thank you but don't see how that addresses the issue.

Comment: The problem can be that you are trying to supply to Predicate instance of NSManagedObject, that generally doesn't exists in it. SQL and core data operate by fields and identifiers, and managed objects limited to Context it was fetched at. Try to supply object ID instead. `NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@",#keyPath(Entry.project.objectID), proj.objectID)`